# punctuation after a fraction in math mode

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I use to [punctuate my equations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22535/do-mathematical-equations-require-punctuation).

In math mode, when the last "word" is a fraction, I raise the final point using `\cdot` like in

```
x = \frac{3}{2} \cdot
```

so that the "." is at the same height as the fraction bar. So my questions are:

- Is it good practice?
- Is there an equivalent of `\cdot` for the comma?

Comment: Is it good practice? No, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @egreg, the punctuation is part of the sentence structure and so should use the text fonts, if you can't avoid needing sentence punctuation in the display use something like `\quad\text{.}`  (or `\quad\text{,}`).

Comment: Are the `\quad`s really necessary? I usually put them with no space or, if it looks bad, with some `\;` or `\:` sometimes.

Comment: @Manuel No any space that looks good in the circumstances (I don't think any position really looks good but sometimes it can't be avoided) a quad (1em) might be too much I agree.

Comment: I will avoid them as much as possible as you and @egreg suggest, Thanks :-)